# Laravel chat App with 2 different user types

Tags: database-design

I'm losing my cool trying to figure out the most scalable schema for a chat app with 2 different user types.

User and Provider (Admin) Ive been trying to use this as a template as it incorporates group messaging (The provider account may send a message to many users - in a group) https://www.tome01.com/efficient-schema-design-for-a-chat-app-using-postgresql

I did try it using a polymorphic pivot table but thats just causing me more headaches. Can someone provide a scalable solution please? A user will have conversations? A conversation will have all the messages Will it work the same for the Provider? And I guess I need to record who sent the message right?

So far I have something like this

**Conversations**
id
provider_id
user_id

**Messages**
conversation_id
content
sender_type

How would the pivot table work? Would I need one for each User type?

Thanks